# "Malformed request" error when making a call in Twilio Android client

Tags: android, request, voip, twilio, malformed

I'm trying to integrate the Twilio client into a larger application. Everything seems to work fine until I call `device.connect(parameters, connectionListener)`. I get the `31100  Generic Malformed Request` error and that's it.

On the same device, using the same Twilio account and the same Twilio application, the sample code supplied with the Twilio Android SDK (MonkeyPhone) works perfectly.

I can't find any more details about what the error means or what are the possible causes. While I'm assuming that I'm sending invalid data, I don't see how is that possible. The Capability Token is OK, I've verified it against the one generated in the MonkeyPhone sample app. Creating a `Device` works fine, no errors. The error is thrown even when I'm not sending any parameters in the `connect()` method. The `onConnecting()` method of the `ConnectionListener` gets called, but then the `onDisconnected(Connection inConnection, int inErrorCode, String inErrorMessage)` is called with the `Malformed Request` error.

The code for the Voice TwiML is working fine, it's just a simple PHP script generating the most simple `<Dial>` verb possible:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>someone</Dial>
</Response>
```

Other specific information... I'm running another service in my application, used to do various other operations. Could this interfere in some way? Also, I'm using a trial account and I'm living in Romania, where calling real phone numbers is not supported (but I'm not using phone numbers anyway). Could this affect me in any way?

I apologize in advance for throwing the huge wall of code, but I hope a second pair of eyes can spot something wrong. This is the version of the code most similar to the MonkeyPhone sample. The only difference is that I'm using an AsyncTask to get the capability token (the `JsonAsyncRequestWithError` class.

```
public class MonkeyPhone implements Twilio.InitListener, DeviceListener {
private static final String TAG = "MonkeyPhone";

private Context context;
private Device device;
private Connection connection;

public MonkeyPhone(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    Twilio.initialize(context, this /* Twilio.InitListener */);
}

@Override
/* Twilio.InitListener method */
public void onInitialized() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Twilio SDK is ready");

    // the Emulator has a somewhat unique "product" name
    String clientName = "doug";

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://teamphoenix.zzl.org/capability.php?ClientName=" + clientName);

    JsonAsyncRequestWithError asyncRequestWithError = new JsonAsyncRequestWithError(context, "test", new AsyncRequestWithErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(AsyncRequestResponse response, Object destination) {
            createDevice(response.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResult(AsyncRequestResponse response, Object destination) {

        }
    });

    asyncRequestWithError.execute(get);

}

public void createDevice(String token) {
    try {
        device = Twilio.createDevice(token, this /* DeviceListener */);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SpringshotPhoneActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        device.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    }
}

@Override
/* Twilio.InitListener method */
public void onError(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Twilio SDK couldn't start: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener method */
public void onStartListening(Device inDevice) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device is now listening for incoming connections");
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener method */
public void onStopListening(Device inDevice) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device is no longer listening for incoming connections");
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener method */
public void onStopListening(Device inDevice, int inErrorCode, String inErrorMessage) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device is no longer listening for incoming connections due to error " + inErrorCode + ": " + inErrorMessage);
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener method */
public boolean receivePresenceEvents(Device inDevice) {
    return false; // indicate we don't care about presence events
}

@Override
/* DeviceListener method */
public void onPresenceChanged(Device inDevice, PresenceEvent inPresenceEvent) {
}

public void connect(String phoneNumber) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
    parameters.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
/// ---------------- THIS IS THE CALL THAT FAILS ------------------------------------//
    connection = device.connect(parameters, null /* ConnectionListener */);
    if (connection == null)
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
}

public void disconnect() {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
        connection = null;
    }
}

public void handleIncomingConnection(Device inDevice, Connection inConnection) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device received incoming connection");
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
    connection = inConnection;
    connection.accept();
}

@Override
protected void finalize() {
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
    if (device != null)
        device.release();
}
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Apparently, I had to read the InputStream from the server using the UTF-8 encoding (even if there are no special characters in the token).

```
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");

    int bin;
    while ((bin = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) >= 0) {
        out.append(buf, 0, bin);
    }

    return out.toString();
```

Comment: did you implement twilio code for incoming call in background Service ??

Comment: Sorry, it has been a long time, I don't remember.